# post full image on user wall

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I m using latest php sdk. I can post to wall with this api. message,picture can be posted to user wall. But the picture is as thumbnail and as link.
Bu I saw some apps on facebook which post full image in wall.
How can I do this. So that PHP genered image can be posted to user wall with full size.
thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into [Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/) on open graph actions.  By marking an action as explicitly sharing, the post is treated like a status update and has a chance to be shown as a standalone story with a full size picture (such as Instagram, Foursquare, etc.)